# Read XML with different tagname from Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I know there are loads of examples online, but there is one particularity in my XML which is posing some problems. 
In fact, I need to loop through my XML and read the Tagname and the text for   ***cars***. Issue is that the tag name is different for all elements;

```
<Vehicles>
   <cars>        
        <Toyota> Test 1 </Toyota>
        <BMW> Test 2 </BMW>
        <VW> Test 3 </VW>
        <Ferrari> Test 4 </Ferrari> 
   </cars> 
</Vehicles>
```

What I have here will loop through the Cars but will return only Toyota.
How do I read the rest, since the tagnames are all different;

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var x, y, z, i, xmlDoc, txt;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  txt = "";
  x = xmlDoc.documentElement;     
  y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cars")[0];
  z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Toyota");

 // Output 
 for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) { 
    txt += z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
 }
 document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = txt; 
}
```

Any idea how I can loop through all the children of ***cars***, without having to mention the tag name, and return me both the tagname itself and the text?

Comment: hint: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cars")[0].children` is a collection of nodes that are children of `cars`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName('cars')[0]` returns a node ... children of nodes are in node.children

```
let models = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('cars')[0].children).map(({nodeName:model, textContent:text}) => ({model, text}))
```

models will be an array of

```
{ model: "model name", text: "text content of model tag" }
```

Comment: That's an interesting answer. Thanks mate ;)

Answer (score 1):

**You can access child node from cars node directly.**

try below code, hope this helps

Note: I haven't executed the code, but i hope it will work

```
    function myFunction(xml) {
   var x, y, z, i, xmlDoc, txt;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  txt = "";
  x = xmlDoc.documentElement;     
  y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cars")[0];

 // Output 
 for (i = 0; i < y.children.length; i++) { 
    txt += y.children[i].nodeName + "<br>";
 }
 document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = txt; 
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your prompt response but it is not working. I'm getting _null_ as output

Comment: corrected, i had to use children property instead of childNode

Comment: I am having an error with the `children.length`, saying it is undefined? Anything related to my code or is it the xml file? thnx

Comment: recheck your xml, may be in your xml, the first "cars" element has no children

Comment: Ok got it.. In fact IE doesn't support `children` but `ChildNodes`. Else, its working fine. Many thanks